# Php outputs mxml for Flash player

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have some ideas about flex and php comunation, and i want your suggestions and answers of the problem. My flex project will communicate with PHP that will output xml code, Actionscript will get this xml code (got from php) and add some objects at run time. But I sought that it would be easier that PHP file itself echo_ed MXML code and flash player should do anything else without Actionscript object creating on live. So is it possible to do this?

Comment: I think mxml is compiled to as3 from the flex compiler. I don't think you can load ii into a flash program and compile it on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this in a real word application:) A MXML file is compiled by the flex compiler into a swf file that is played by the Flash Player. Your PHP back-end has the job of passing **data** to the flash player.

Now, in a fantasy world, where there are unicorns to entertain the user while a web application is loading I think that this could work:

1. PHP creates MXML(blame the unicorns for this)
2. The MXML file is passed to the flex compiler and compiled
3. the resulting swf file is send to the webbrowser
4. after some unicorn fun the user starts clicking around

But why would someone do something like this?

Comment: and this proves my theory that everything is better with unicorns mixed in ;)

Comment: Is it worth nothing that what you describe it pretty much how Flex 1 / 1.5 worked?  I don't believe it was very effective; which is why they did a big "About face" on the approach.

Comment: +1 because I think you have the best answer; although the unicorn reference actually detracts from the professionalism.

Answer (score 0):

No, Flex is a compiled language.

MXML is just a tag based syntax to define portions of code.  Just like actionscript, that code is compiled into a swf.

It may resemble XML or HTML, but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible. Flex need to be compiled into swf to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to think of MXML as a pre-compiler tool for ActionScript. It isn't really even used to output the final swf file, it is translated first by the "pre-compiler" into the equivalent of an .as file. Only after it is translated does the "compiler" add the class definition to the swf.

While it is possible to get PHP to output MXML and then call mxmlc (? can't remember the command line command to compile a swf) on it to output a swf, you're far better off coming up with some custom XML parsing engine of your own and dynamically add/remove objects based on that.